# Why is the Displacement Modifier not doing anything?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I'm doing the CG Cookie Tutorial on the rocket ship. I added a cube, added the triangulate modifier, added the displacement modifier, added a cloud texture to the displacement, set the displacement strength to 5.0, and yet my cube still looks like a cube.

[image: My Cube]

In the tutorial he ends up with a cube resembling this:

[image: His cube]

Here are the texture settings:

[image: settings]

Comment: Could you post a pic of your node setup?

Comment: I haven't gotten to nodes. I'm going through the tutorial and I have yet to deal with them. I've looked in the Shading workspace but there are no nodes there.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're doing it through modifiers only. Give me a sec..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all modifiers from the cube and start again.

First, add a *Bevel* modifier. This gives supporting geometry, so when you add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, the cube doesn't turn into a sphere (Try for yourself if you don't believe me).

So, add the *Subdivision Surface* modifier next, (this gives extra geometry to displace - I set number of subdivisions to 3 to start).

Lastly, add the *Displace* modifier, pick the cloud texture, set the strength to 0.5 and you should get this:

[image: Displacement]

So, the order of modifiers (from top to bottom) is *Bevel*, *Subdivision Surface*, and lastly, *Displace*. You can control the detail of the clouds by increasing the subdivisions of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

If you need to triangulate, you can add a *Triangulate* modifier afterwards.

EDIT- Is this more to your liking?

[image: NewDisplace]

If so, all I did was subdivide the cube once, then I placed a *Bevel*, *Displace*, and *Triangulate* modifier in the order shown. You can play with both the Bevel values as well as the Displacement Strength and Midlevel to get different shapes and sizes.

As for the colors - they are in user preferences - Theme is "GreenHorizon"
[image: Colors]

Comment: "*First, add a Bevel modifier. This gives supporting geometry, so when you add a Subdivision Surface modifier, the cube doesn't turn into a sphere*" Why not simply set *Subdiv* to *Simple*?

Comment: Good point - Do that instead,

Comment: Hey. I did what you said and my cube turned out just like yours. It worked but not like I wanted it to. I edited the post to be more accurate about what I wanted.

Comment: Couple side questions.. Can you add images to comment responses or do you have to edit the post? Next was how you changed your viewport colors on the map to be black and turquoise. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussions. If you have further details add them to the original question by editing the post. If you have a different issue post a new question, make sure it hasn't been asked before.

Comment: Yes, you answered my question. I don't know how to upvote to mark my question solved without the 15 reputation points but thank you.